# Backend Processing of SET Statement and use of Continue and Leave Statement in SAS

Tags: sas

I am beginner to SAS Programming.
I have written a piece of code to understand the stuff, but I am not getting why after getting the continue statement it is going to the output a statement.
Given below is the code :

```
data a B;
put 'entering do DATASTEP' ;
do i=1 to 4;
    put 'entering do loop'"   " i;
if (i=1) then do;
    put 'value of i is 1'"   " i;

    put 'Entering the loop' ;
    put j=_N_;
    if _N_ = 2 then continue;
    set sashelp.class(firstobs=1 obs=5);
    put 'Ouside the loop';
    output a;
    end;
if (i=2) then do;
    put 'value of i is 2'"   " i;

    put 'Entering the loop' ;
    put j=_n_;
    set sashelp.class(firstobs=6 obs=10);
    put 'Ouside the loop';
    output B;
    end;
end;
put 'GETING OUT OF THE DATASTEP';
run;
```

For more clarity about my doubt request to please run this and then we can have a discussion about the output dataset and the log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you write code that you don't understand? What exactly are you trying to to?

Comment: Thanks Cristina for responding. I am not trying to achieve any requirement out of this code. I am just trying to understand how the output is getting generated into both the datasets and why the Continue Statement is not working as per its specification. According to me, in the Dataset A there should be only 4 records as I have used Continue Statement for _N_ =2 but I am getting 5 records into that. Second Record should not get into the Dataset A as the continue Statement is before the Output A. Please let me know, if you got my problem.

Comment: Aha, ok! Thanks for the clarification -- you could perhaps add this information to your post, to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the `CONTINUE` is working fine.

Normally SAS will stop the data step when you read past the end of the input data. Without the `CONTINUE` statement that would be when it tried to read from the first SET statement for the 6th time. But since you skipped it once it will stop when it tries to execute the second SET statement for the 6th time.

Here is a simplified version of what your data step is doing. Notice how it reads the records in 1,6,7,2,8,3,9,4,10,5 order.

```
data sample;
  do i=1 to 10; output; end;
run;

data _null_ ;
  if _n_^=2 then do;
    set sample (firstobs=1 obs=5);
    put i=;
  end;
  set sample (firstobs=6 obs=10);
  put i=;
run;

i=1
i=6
i=7
i=2
i=8
i=3
i=9
i=4
i=10
i=5
```